# Copy QR CODE image to clipboard and paste to share. I use Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have created a QRcode with  and i want to copy it to clipboarb and i dont know how. Hope everyone can help.
It was encoded by me to base64 and now I need to copy it to clipboard and paste it in (word, email,...) it is a QRCode image.

Comment: Can I be more specific in Vuejs?

Comment: I does not matter whether the image was generated using Vue component or by other means. The problem has nothing to do with Vue...